# how do I use memcpy() function?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to store some binary data obtained from read() in my buffer using the memcpy() function.

Basically, I want to store buf in my buffer:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 256
//...
char *
httpget(const char * domain, const int port, const char * headers)
{
    int sockfd;
    int buf_size = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    struct sockaddr_in  sock_addr; 
    struct hostent  *   host;

    char * buffer;
    char * newbuf;
    char * tbuf;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if( sockfd == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    host = gethostbyname(domain);

    if( NULL == host )
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(&sock_addr, '\0', sizeof(sock_addr));
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy( &sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            host -> h_addr,
            host -> h_length );

    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr)) == -1)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    if( write(sockfd, headers, strlen(headers) + 1) == -1)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    buffer = malloc( MAX_BUFFER_SIZE );
    tbuf = malloc( MAX_BUFFER_SIZE );

    if(buffer == NULL || tbuf == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int bytesloaded = 0;
    int readed;

    while( (readed = read(sockfd, tbuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0 )
    {   
        if(bytesloaded + readed >= buf_size)
        {
            buf_size = buf_size + MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;  
            newbuf = realloc(buffer, buf_size);

            if(newbuf != NULL)
            {
                buffer = newbuf; 
            }
            else 
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        memcpy(buffer, tbuf, readed);
        bytesloaded += readed;
    }

    close(sockfd);
    printf("buffer = %s", buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

but when I printf("%s",buffer); I get only the HTTP Headers and `�PNG` characteres from binary that have 7007 content-length. how to fix this? I hope this is clear for you. any help is very appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this re-typed code? `buffe` sure looks like a typo that a compiler would catch. It really is best if your shortened code really does fail -- it's no fun to debug code that only exists on this website...

Comment: Note that if the second memory allocation fails, you will leak the 256 bytes allocated in the first memory allocation.

Comment: @sarnold: Was typo. I added my real code.

Comment: Significantly better! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
memcpy(buffer + bytesloaded, buf, readed);
```

You aren't seeing the entire response when you try to dump it using  `printf("%s",buffer)` because the `.png` image being sent in the response is binary data that's likely to contain a null `'\0'` byte, and the `printf()` will stop at that point.

You have all sorts of other options to examine the data returned in the response (or information about it): look at `buffer` in the debugger, dump the `bytesloaded` variable, dump `buffer` using a function that will convert it to hex for display, and/or write the response body (after the headers and the CR/LF that follows the headers) to a `.png` file and take a look at it in something that will display an image.

Comment: I update my code. check out. I receive only the HTTP Headers, for example: `HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2012 01:01:54 GMT
Server: Mono.WebServer2/0.2.0.0 Unix
Last-Modified: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 14:50:48 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Length: 7007
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: close

�PNG
`

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in memcpy, referring to buffe instead of buffer, and while it is possible that it only appears in the post and not in your actual code (I don't believe it would compiled with it) if it is then it is definitely the problem.

UPDATE: While other answers suggest that there might be a null byte, there is no where in the png header specification that a null byte should be part of the header so the only place it might be is the body, but since you are receiving no data then the only option might be if it is the first thing in the body something I believe is really a rear case, so you might try with a different source of information such as another image or another url, and if the problem persists on all png images then it is something between printf and the header (and as such if it is there a null byte in the header then it is something worth to invastigate anyway).

However note that after the letters PNG comes a CRLF and then comes EOF, and while it would be interesting if printf would have a problem with it, still if this is the problem then dumping to a file must not be the solution either unless you open it with a png viewer.

In fact you haven't included your socket source, and as such if is code that you have written yourself make sure that it does not stop on the first EOF since it is part of the png header.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `printf(3)` formatting directive `%s` will print bytes as characters until it encounters an ASCII `NUL` character. The [PNG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) could allow a `NUL` perhaps as soon as the ninth byte -- and the first eight bytes are the `0x89`, `PNG`, and then some white-space characters to discover specific kinds of white-space mangling.

I suggest using a different `printf(3)` format specifier to see the data in question -- or write it to a debugging file, so that you can edit it with common hex editors to validate its contents.